# Функция hash() и оператор not

Tags: python

Можно ли выполнить функцию `hash()` и оператор `not` над *любыми* объектами?
С массивами из модуля `numpy` не выполняются, почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы "над объектом" можно было выполнить `hash` у объекта (класса) должна быть определена функция-член `__hash__`. По умолчанию, у пользовательских классов эта функция определена (вероятно возвращает что-то типа `hash` от адреса). У стандартных питоновских коллекций (и массивов numpy видимо) определен атрибут `__hash__ = None`, поэтому они не хэшируются.

Для того, чтобы можно было (осмысленно) использовать `not my_object`, `if my_object: ...` у объекта/класса должна быть определена функция `__nonzero__` или `__bool__` или `__len__` (иначе любой объект будет приводится к True). Чтобы запретить использование объектов класс в булевом контексте, у класс надо прописать атрибут `__nonzero__ = None` (2-й) или `__bool__ = None` (3-й Питон):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return self.value % 2 == 0

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Foo:{}>".format(self.value)


foo = Foo(2)
bar = Foo(3)
if not foo:
    print "not foo" # не напечатается
if not bar:
    print "not bar" # напечатается

print hash(foo) # -> 2

d = {foo: 2, bar: 3} # объекты класса можно использовать в качестве ключей словаря т.к. определена ф-я __hash__
print d # -> {<Foo:2>: 2, <Foo:3>: 3}
```

P.S. У меня 2-й Python, но это в данном случае не имеет значения.

Comment: А print можно выполнить с любым?

Comment: Принт с любым. Для того, чтобы выводить на печать что-то свое вместо `<__main__.Foo object at 0x00000000021C7860>` нужно определить ф-и `__repr__` и/или `__str__`

Comment: 1- с точность до наоборот. Все объекты поддерживают hash,  кроме тех, для которых явно запрещено (`__hash__=None` в классе). Хэширование выключают обычно у изменяемых объектов таких как numpy.array 2- никаких методов не нужно определять (объект пользовательского класса считается True в булевом контексте). Можно переопределить в `__bool__` (новое имя для `__nonzero__`), `__len__` (пустая коллекция считается False)

Comment: @jfs спасибо, поправил ответ